# how to debug a controller not being run

Tags: 8, routes, page-controller

my code below results in a page not found when I browse to the path.  How can I debug what is going wrong? I dont see any errors and I have cleared the cache.

```
mymodule.content:
  path: '/admin/viewfiles'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\FileView::content'
    _title: 'File Operations Module Description'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access administration pages'
```

Comment: See [Adding a basic controller](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-a-basic-controller). Did you create the `src/Controller` folders? Did you name your controller file `FileView.php`? Does your controller extend the `ControllerBase` class? Did you namespace your controller?

Comment: Yes yes and yes . I did all that . If not I would get an error when running drush

Comment: So far everything looks good, @Diana can you post your controller's code?

Comment: Is the routing file named correctly?

Comment: Remove the initial backslash from the controller namespace + make sure the module is neabled + make sure you have cleared cache after making changes in routing file.

Comment: @IvanJaros that initial slash is def not the problem, [in the Drupal docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/add-a-routing-file) it has it.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling your module, after creating the route?

Comment: thanks i had a misspelling in the router name. thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks i had a misspelling in the router name. thank you all